# When uploading a file in POST, req.body is {} in Node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, axios

## React code - FileUploader.js

```
// React - FileUplader.js

    const handleSubmission = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(isSelected === false){
            alert("load the file");
        }
        else{
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("certificate",selectFile);

            // API CALL
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/upload", {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData,
                headers : {
                    "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data"
                }
            }).then((response) =>response.json())
            .then((result)=>{
                console.log("Success : ", result);
            })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.error("Error : ",error);
                });
        }
    };
```

## Nodejs code - Server.js

```
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

app.post('/upload', async function(req ,res){
    try {
        const file = req.files; // undeifined
        const bodyData = req.body; // {}
        console.log("file : ",file);
        console.log("bodyData : ",bodyData);

        res.status(200).send({
            message: "FILE RECEIVED!"
        });
    } catch(error){
        res.send("ERROR")};
});
```

## Problem

Why req.body is {} in node js

I tried using MULTER but got the same result

MDN says that FormData object is not a simple object, but a special object created for XMLHttpRequest transmission and cannot be recorded with the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your front end code is correct. You did not set up multer. Multer is actually a middleware, will be listening to `multipart/form-data`. [check the docs][1]

> Multer is a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data, which
> is primarily used for uploading files.
>
> Multer adds a body object and a file or files object to the request
> object. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the
> form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the
> form.

to handle files on node.js environment, write a middleware:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const { randomBytes } = require("crypto");

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, randomBytes(4).toString("hex") + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

module.exports = multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter }).single("image"); //image is the field name
```

Then use it in `express app`

```
const multer = require("./middlewares/multer");

app.use(cors()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(multer);
```

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

[1]: [http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html#:~:text=Multer%20is%20a%20node.,multipart%2Fform%2Ddata%20](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html#:%7E:text=Multer%20is%20a%20node.,multipart%2Fform%2Ddata%20)).

Comment: Multer isn't the only option. I actually find [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) a little more beginner friendly

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve the problem.